# Symfony2, how can I skip printing repeated values in a loop in twig templates?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a table in this loop:

```
{% for key, value in boxes %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{ value.boxnum }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.code }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.total }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.qty }}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Which gives a table of:

```
  Box       Code   Total   Qty  
3096362    130291   27     216  
3096362    140001   18     144  
3096362    140003    4      32  
3096362    140013   14     112
```

How can I get the Box # column to only print once since the rest are just repeats?

Comment: You could set a variable to equal the box num on each iteration. Before hand check if the current boxnum equals the check variable and print accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can do

```
{% set bnum = '' %}
{% for key, value in boxes %}
 <tr>
    {% if bnum != value.boxnum %}
      {% set bnum = value.boxnum  %}
      <td>{{ value.boxnum }}</td>
    {% else %}
      <td></td>
    {% endif %}
    <td>{{ value.code }}</td>
    <td>{{ value.total }}</td>
    <td>{{ value.qty }}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```